Show div based on changed span class
Let's say that I have two span elements. Class is changing width "selected" based on which one is selected. I just need to know when span2 is selected or not.
<span class="swatch swatch-image span1">
<span class="swatch swatch-image span2 selected">

I'm trying to listen which one is selected (which one has class "selected") and then show or don't show div in other place. Is it possible?
I've tried this way:
let targetNode = document.getElementsByClassName('swatch swatch-image span2 selected');

const config = { attributes: true, childList: false, subtree: false, attributeFilter: ['class'] };

const callback = function(mutationsList, observer) {
    for (let mutation of mutationsList) {
        if (mutation.attributeName === "class") {
            var classList = mutation.target.className;
            if(/red/.exec(classList).length > 0) {
                console.log('Found match');
            }
        }
    }
};

const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

observer.observe(targetNode, config);

observer.disconnect();

Is MutationObserver is proper way to listen which span is selected? I'm not familiar with javascript, do I need to call MutationObserver somehow after constructing code?

"I've tried this way:" - you appear to be checking whether the element's classes contain red, that doesn't match your HTML code or problem description.

X/Y problem? WHAT is changing the span? WHY not just add your code there?

show or don't show div in other place it may be possible to do this without javascript at all - depending on where "other place" is

@mplungjan This is part of Wordpress plugin code, Span gets class selected while you click it. Then value of span is taken from data-value. Didn't seen this red fragment. @CBroe I've found this code here in one of the threads about MutationObserver, but after changing nothing's changed. I've got Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'observe' on 'MutationObserver': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'. in console

@JaromandaX without javascript? How? How to check if class of span changed when clicked without javascript? I'm familiar with PHP and I know it's possibilities, but I need ti listen of class changing while clicking on span element

I can't speculate without knowing the full details of your HTML

https://jsfiddle.net/wa7o0p5b/ - naturally you have the code that changes which "span" is "selected" already, right?

Yup, @mplungjan answer did the trick

Find the closest container enclosing the spans and delegate


window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',() => { // when page has loaded
  const container = document.getElementById('someContainer'); // change as needed 
  container.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const tgt = e.target.closest('span.swatch');
    if (!tgt) return; // not a swatch
    console.log(tgt.textContent, 'clicked')
    document.getElementById('showWhenSpan2').hidden = !tgt.matches('.span2')
  });

// somewhere else out of your control
  document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const tgt = e.target.closest('span.swatch');
    if (!tgt) return; // not a swatch
    document.querySelectorAll('span.swatch').forEach(span => span.classList.toggle('selected',span===tgt))
  });



});
.selected { border: 1px solid red; }
<div id="someContainer">
...

<span class="swatch swatch-image span1 selected">Span 1</span>
<span class="swatch swatch-image span2">Span 2</span>


...
</div>

<div id="showWhenSpan2" hidden>Shown when span 2 is clicked</div>




Super happy you didn't show this with a MutationObserver

Alright, @mplungjan answer works like a charm. It's really nice and clean code. Thank you. I was able to add id of div which is parent of span.swatch but I had to find nearest  of a div which I was trying to hide/show because I need to show and hide whole tr element:
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => { // when page has loaded
  const container = document.getElementById('someContainer'); // change as needed 
  const container2 = document.getElementById('someOtherContainer'); // looking for div of tr element
  const tr = container2.closest('tr');
  if (!tr) return;
  tr.style.display = "none";
  container.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const tgt = e.target.closest('span.swatch');
    if (!tgt) return; // not a swatch
    if (!tgt.matches('.span2')) {
      tr.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      tr.removeAttribute("style");
    }
  });
});

So it's modified code for hide <tr> at start and toggle display: none or remove whole style element in case of clicking span2 element
Javascript is not so hard as I thought

Is this an answer? If not, please just update the question with relevant HTML so I can improve my answer. The code you posted here is a bit strange, as if it is only half the actual code

Yup, sorry, forgot to copy some code, already edited my answer
